# Use of undeclared identifier "ACAccountStore"

Tags: ios, acaccountstore

I'm trying to use the ios Account Framework. I already added the Accounts.Framework in my build phases, but I still get the error

```
Use of undeclared identifier "ACAccountStore"
```

Anyone know why? Social.Framework works fine for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you make sure to include the header?

#### Objective-C

```
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
```

#### Swift

```
import Accounts
```

Comment: I didn't. Now it works. Somehow I didn't import the <Social/Social.h> but my code with SLComposeViewController worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you forgot to import it?

```
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
```

**EDIT:** Now I know where it's declared, so updated my answer. :)

Comment: Yeah that was the problem.